# How to position table2 under the table1?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to position table2 under the table1, if the position of table1 is centered and width of table1 is larger than table2?

HTML

```
<table id="table1" align="center" style="width:150px;">
<tr>
    <td height="50">Table 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td height="50">Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#table1 {
   background: #ccc
}
#table2 {
   background: #666;
}
```

question picture

https://prnt.sc/i9r851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...place them both inside a parent container element and apply the following properties:

```
.parentdiv {
  display:table;
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That's probably because I added a `.parentdiv` class and you added a `#parentdiv` id instead

Answer (score 0):

First I have put both the tables into a div and centered that div than on ids-'table1' and 'table2' i have used float left to make them one under another.

```
<div id="center">
<table id="table1" style="width:150px;">
<tr>
    <td height="50">Table 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td height="50">Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table1 {
background: #ccc;
float:left;
}
#table2 {
background: #666;
float:left;
clear:left;
}
#center{
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  position: relative
}
```

Comment: Table elements are not centered to the page!